# SQLAlchemy .all() not returning all when called with filter_by()

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

so whenever i Order.query.all() the results returned are complete, but when Order.query.filter_by(id=current_user.id).all() I only get one result back.

DB model setup:

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(30), nullable = False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(60), unique = True, nullable = False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable = False)
    phone = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable = False)
    country = db.Column(db.String(30), nullable = False)
    city = db.Column(db.String(30), nullable = False)
    address = db.Column(db.String(350), nullable = False)
    kaftl = db.Column(db.String(30), nullable = False)
    order = db.relationship('Order', backref='buyer', lazy=True) 

class Order(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable = False, default=datetime.utcnow)
    order = db.Column(db.Text, nullable = False)
    kaftl = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable = False)
    price = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable = False)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)
```

HTML just in case it's useful:

```
{% for order in orders %}
       {{ order.price }}
       {{ order.order }}

   {% endfor %}
```

Comment: i should mention that orders = Order.query.filter_by(id=current_user.id) doesn't work properly

Comment: Model.query.fiter_by works properly. Your code may not. If filter_by(arg).all() returns nothing, it means that you have no result. If it returns one result, it means that one result matches. You can check the SQL query generated by SQLALCHEMY and test it on your database and see what is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think instead of id, you should use user_id as;

```
Order.query.filter_by(user_id=current_user.id).all()
```

Because id is unique for each object and when you call that code, it actually returns you the order with id= current_user.id.